# Getting "does not match the reply address" error in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have changed my reply url in the azure ad tenant application.

I have updated this reply url in the get request for getting the authorization code from azure , along with the client id of the application.

The thing is 
I am getting this response

```
{ "error":"invalid_grant",
  "error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50011: The reply address 'newly updated reply url which i send in get request'
  does not match the reply address 'old reply url which I changed in AZURE' 
  provided when requesting Authorization code.
  Trace ID: 0e05b301-c7b1-48bd-ab78-ce7c2b12d74d
  Correlation ID: 17f5ae64-850d-4767-823c-f0e7ad2c49da
  Timestamp: 2016-03-28 12:02:17Z","error_codes":[70002,50011],
  "timestamp":"2016-03-28 12:02:17Z",
  "trace_id":"0e05b301-c7b1-48bd-ab78-ce7c2b12d74d",
  "correlation_id":"17f5ae64-850d-4767-823c-f0e7ad2c49da"
}
```

I am sure , that there is no issue in the client id , which i pass.

Why is it pointing to the old value ??